# Horizon Line Detection via Canny and Hough

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, edge-detection

I am trying to detect horizon line in python. In order to achieve my goal, firstly I used canny edge detection algorithm. [sea.jpg](https://pasteboard.co/8cTgJGisV.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

gray = cv2.imread('images/sea.jpg')
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
```

After edge detection, I applied hough transform to image.

```
minLineLength=100
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=10,theta=np.pi/180, 
threshold=1,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=80)

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(gray, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imwrite('images/output.jpg',gray)

cv2.imshow('output',gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But at the end, I [output.jpg](https://pasteboard.co/8cY4KXbRP.jpg) like this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure whether it is better for your problem, but typically I recommend Line Segment Detection over Canny Edges.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to filter out lines with a low theta value. I don't think you are filtering anything at the moment. Try making a new list of lines with only lines where y1 == y2, in other words horizontal lines.

Comment: I am confused about what I have to do. Can you give example?

Comment: I'm hoping someone else can cause I only started with Python this week so don't really know about the syntax. Sorry :(